# jQuery : trouble with Shift+Tab onkeydown

Tags: jquery

The scenario:

We have 3 boxes that can receive any letter or number combinations as input.  The first box can have a max of 3 characters, the second box must be exactly 7 and the last needs to be 2.

I was trying to get a jQuery function in place to take the user from the first box to the second once they'd typed 3 characters and then from the 2nd to the 3rd after 7 characters and then from the 3rd on to the button after 2 characters.  I also want this function to be fairly generic so that I can use it from other controls so I set up the following:

```
function moveOn(e, objID, nextID, howLong) {
        if (!(e.keyCode == 9)) {
            if ($(objID).val().length >= (howLong)) {
                $(nextID).select();
            }
        }
    }
```

What is causing me fits is Shift+Tab.  I'm trying to catch it with that if(keyCode == 9) check but because it's keyup, the shift key could come up a split second before the Tab in which case the event triggers on the Shift key (16) instead of the Tab (9).  I can't ignore all Shift catches since the user will most likely be using capital letters in at least one of the fields.

Shift+Tab is coming into play when they type in the first value and then realize they made a mistake so they want to go back.  Our workforce is very keyboard-driven so they will almost always use Shift+Tab to try to go back and fix that.

Is there some trick I'm missing for making this work fluidly?

TIA.

Comment: Just FYI, you want to give `focus()`

Comment: You want to automatically move focus to the next field when they've entered the correct number of characters into the current field. So where does shift or tab come into it? I'm obviously missing something...

Comment: Why would I want to use focus() over select().  If there's a value already in that next field then I want to have it immediately selected so that they can type over it.  focus(), imo, always makes the assumption that you're only planning on appending the value currently there ... which I find to usually not be the case.

Comment: Added some description about where Shift+Tab is coming into play

Comment: Going back to the focus() vs select() part ... I did add something for determining if I'm going to a text box or a link/button and handling that appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that ignoring the key code for shift (16) will cause you any problems. When the user releases shift, it would ignore it. It will then fire a separate onkeydown event for any other keys they press, no matter if shift is still held down or not. You can test it here: http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Comment: tried that ... e.shiftKey works but it doesn't always register the keyCode as 9 ... sometimes it registers 16 (the Shift key) in which case my if() is not catching.

Comment: That was the answer.  I was stuck on the concept that I couldn't ignore the Shift key because it could be happening in combination with an actual alphanumeric keystroke but the reality is that it is happening IN ADDITION to that alphanumeric keystroke which means that I CAN ignore it because the alphanumeric will fire its own event.  

I got hung up on it because of the way my tests with a simple alert were coming back ... because the alert was disrupting the flow and I was never seeing the second keystroke ... just the Shift.  

Thanks